# Variable defined in Guard still require unwrapping immediately afterwards when used

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

**if (stringToURL?.isValidURL)!** <-- Not sure why the complier requires optional chaining on *stringToURL* when it is safely declared in Guard statement.  Also,  string extension for **isValidURL: Bool** always returns Bool but compiler still wants unwrapping.

In this example, *annotation.subtitle* should already be string in URL format but I wanted to confirm.

Trying to use variables defined in guard becomes more convoluted than expected because further unwrapping is needed.  Now I feel that I'm making a few lines of code overly complicated to follow/read with my implementations.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let backupURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    guard let currentAnnotation = view.annotation, var stringToURL = currentAnnotation.subtitle else {
        // currentAnnotation has blank subtitle.  Handle by opening up any website.
        UIApplication.shared.open(backupURL, options: [:])
        return
    }
    if (stringToURL?.isValidURL)!{
        stringToURL = stringToURL?.prependHTTPifNeeded()
        if let url = URL(string: stringToURL!){
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:])
        } else {
            UIApplication.shared.open(backupURL, options: [:])
        }
    }
}

extension String {
var isValidURL: Bool {
    let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
    if let match = detector.firstMatch(in: self, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.endIndex.encodedOffset)) {
        // it is a link, if the match covers the whole string
        return match.range.length == self.endIndex.encodedOffset
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

func prependHTTPifNeeded()-> String{
    let first4 = self.prefix(4)
    if first4 != "http" {
        return "http://" + self
    } else {
        return self
    }
}
```

}

The code block executes properly.
annotation.subtitle = "https://www.yahoo.com"  <--- yahoo opens

annotation.subtitle = "www.yahoo.com"  <--- yahoo opens

annotation.subtitle = "yahoo"  <--- google.com opens because we did not have a valid URL string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `currentAnnotation.subtitle` is a `String??`, because `subtitle` is not only a `String?`, itself, but it is also an optional property of `MKAnnotation` protocol. So a simple unwrap only verifies that the optional protocol `subtitle` was implemented, but not that the resulting `String?` was not `nil`. You have to unwrap that, too.

But you can do `guard var stringToURL = view.annotation?.subtitle as? String else { ... }`, and it will be properly unwrapped to a `String`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let backupURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com”)!

    guard var stringToURL = view.annotation?.subtitle as? String else {
        UIApplication.shared.open(backupURL)
        return
    }

    if stringToURL.isValidURL {
        stringToURL = stringToURL.prependHTTPifNeeded()
        let url = URL(string: stringToURL) ?? backupURL
        UIApplication.shared.open(url)
    }
}
```

Note, that will open the `backupURL` if no string is provided, but if a string was provided and wasn’t a valid URL, it won’t do anything. So perhaps you meant the following, which will open `backupURL` if it can’t open `stringToURL`:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    let backupURL = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!

    guard var stringToURL = view.annotation?.subtitle as? String,
        stringToURL.isValidURL else {
            UIApplication.shared.open(backupURL)
            return
    }

    stringToURL = stringToURL.prependHTTPifNeeded()
    let url = URL(string: stringToURL) ?? backupURL
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Where:

```
extension String {
    var isValidURL: Bool {
        let detector = try! NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue)
        let range = NSRange(startIndex..., in: self)
        return detector.firstMatch(in: self, range: range)?.range == range
    }

    func prependHTTPifNeeded() -> String{
        if prefix(4) != "http" {
            return "http://" + self
        } else {
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and more concise way of re-writing the same code.  I was struggling with both concepts.